# Can Zabbix to monitor parameter from MySQL base?

Tags: zabbix

Is there a way to monitor some data from MySQL for Zabbix 3?
For example, for this query:

```
SELECT SUM(`column1`) FROM `table` where `column2` = "text"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to do that.

- [ODBC monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/odbc_checks) can execute such queries without any additional scripts, but requires configuring odbc.ini
- [External checks](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/external) can run commands/scripts on the Zabbix server or proxy
- [Userparameters](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/userparameters) can execute commands/scripts on Zabbix agents
- You could also have a separate script gather the data and then send it to the Zabbix server using [Zabbix sender](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/concepts/sender)